# az cli command returns 'Bad Request' when using variable but works otherwise

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have this Az cli command that enables backup for a VM that I'd like to use with a script:

```
    #Get required VM ID
getID=$(az vm show\
  --resource-group $resourceGroup \
  --name $vmName \
  --query id | tr -d '"')
  
# Enable backup for VM with the created policy
az backup protection enable-for-vm \
  --resource-group $resourceGroup \
  --vault-name $vaultName \
  --vm $getID \
  --policy-name $policyName
```

this is the official Azure documentation i followed :

```
az backup protection enable-for-vm --resource-group myResourceGroup --vault-name myRecoveryServicesVault --vm $(az vm show -g VMResourceGroup -n MyVm --query id | tr -d '"') --policy-name DefaultPolicy
```

when I run the command using the variable values as options it works fine, However when I use variable it returns an error :

```
Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request'
```

and the problem is with the `--vm` option specifically

Comment: Could you include the full error from the command as well as the output of the $getID variable?
$Output = az backup protection enable-for-vm \
  --resource-group $resourceGroup \
  --vault-name $vaultName \
  --vm $getID \
  --policy-name $policyName
Then I believe the error will be on the object with something like this:
$Output.Exception.Message

Comment: This is the only message that i can capture : Error Message: Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request', unfortunately Microsoft does not provide a good debug mode, cause when I tried to use debug i got misc information and no actual valuable information about the error.

Comment: Dump getId to the console and it’ll probably be obvious. Also, share which runtime environment you’re using (PowerShell, bash, etc) because it could be related to the way it escapes characters

Answer (score 0):

> az cli command returns 'Bad Request' when using variable. **Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request**'

The error **"Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request'"** indicates that there is an issue with the request being sent to `Azure Backup`.

I have used the `--output tsv` option to retrieve the `VM ID` as a tab-separated value, which can then be stored in the `getID` variable.

```
 policyName="DefaultPolicy"
 resourceGroup="Venkat"
 vaultName="vault-lpuxsg4n"
 vmName="linux-vmdemo"
 getID=$(az vm show --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $vmName --query id --output tsv)
 az backup protection enable-for-vm --resource-group $resourceGroup --vault-name $vaultName --vm $getID --policy-name $policyName
```

**Output:**

[image]

If the issue persists, please consider upgrading the **Az CLI** version in case it's currently running on a **lower version**

```
az version
az upgrade
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hello David, I appreciate your efforts in exploring the solution. For reference, I have included the image containing the output window of the Azure CLI run as evidence in the provided answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Venkat V, thank you for your efforts and answer. However, I had the same issue using the --output tsv option as before :
**cmd1** vmID=$(az vm show\
  --resource-group $resourceGroup \
  --name $vmName \
  --query id \
  --output tsv)
**cmd2**  echo $vmID
/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/aa/../backup-vm
**cmd3** az backup protection enable-for-vm \
  --resource-group $resourceGroup \
  --vault-name $vaultName \
  --vm $vmID \
  --policy-name $policyName
**Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request'**

Comment: Please tell me where you are running the script. Are you using Cloud Shell or local PowerShell?